# How to close a popup downloading a file after the download is complete

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I send a query string to popup windows and download files from the server.
I want to close the popup after the download is complete but I don't know how.

My Javascript code that sends the query string is:

```
var url = "../Msg/pgmsgAttachmentDownload.aspx?ID=" + ID;
window.open(url, '_blank', "top=100,left=100,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=670,height=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes", true);
```

My code that downloads a file from the popup page (pgmsgAttachmentDownload.aspx) is:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + newfilename + ";");
response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(bomsgAttachments.FilePath));
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

My code doesn't work in Chrome, but works and closes windows in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

you can use self closing Javascript method in the body onload part of your Download Page:

use this in the head

```js
function windowclose() {
  window.open('', '_self', ''); 
  window.close();
    }
```

and then call the function from the body tag:

```html
<body onload="setTimeout('windowclose()',3000);">
```

this works for me...

Cheers